# PHP MYSQL Updatable Form

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to create a form that you can enter data into mysql using php and then it will update the table on the same page instantly here is what I have

1. Index_test.php: http://pastebin.com/03fndSHG
2. Update.php: http://pastebin.com/jQraSskS
3. index_style.css: (http://)pastebin.com/PhYxttFu

When I submit this I get a double entry in my form and I want the update to be seamless like on the index_test.php it shows a line that says "An entry has been added" and the table refreshes automatically without any movement to another page. I ahve tried finding something with Ajax but nothing I try works

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this, I would use jQuery for the ajax. There's lots of documentation here: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page. It simplifies ajax, if you know how jQuery works. To use jQuery, you'll need to know some javascript as well. Without jQuery, just javascript & php is enough, but trickier because internet explorer does ajax differently than the other browsers.

Without ajax, you should probably submit the form to the same page as the form, which then redraws itself with the new table row. Even with ajax, if the user turns off javascript, then the form needs to submit to the same page, or another page that has the form in it. This is known as progressive enhancement or graceful degradation, meaning, the web page still works if javascript is disabled.

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for but I do appreciate the feedback.